# Time server network

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I want to get the time using the Time protocol found in RFC 868.
I am using python to do that.
here is my code:

```
import socket
server = "time.nist.gov"
port = 37
receive_buffer_size = 4096

mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysocket.connect((server, port))

response_string = mysocket.recv( receive_buffer_size )

mysocket.close

print response_string
```

I'm supposed to get a 32 bit number, but i'm getting garbage!
any idea where is the problem?

Comment: You're receiving a 32-bit binary number into a 4k buffer and printing the entire buffer. Most of will be garbage. Check the _first four bytes_ only.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to do that? Is reducing the size of the buffer enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got the **RAW DATA**

Try this:

```
data, = struct.unpack('!I', response_string)
print "%x " %data
```